# JSON.Net Seralize values don't have quotation marks

Tags: .net, json, format, json.net

The following code:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fooObject,
                                                   new JsonSerializerSettings
                                                       {
                                                           NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,

                                                       });
```

Seralizes a json (string) object of:

> {
>   "fooA":0,
>   "fooB":0,
>   "fooC":false,
>   "fooD":false,
>   "fooE":0,
>   "fooF":0,
>   }

The values are not in quotation marks, such as "fooA":"0". This is the behavior that I want.

Is there a way to enforce this behavior?

Comment: If you want them to be serialized as strings then make them strings instead of numeric types.

Comment: Numbers don't need to be enclosed in quotes in JSON. Why do you need them to be?

Comment: Pushing to an API that wants them in quotation marks. If making them strings is the way to go, I'll go ahead and make that change. Thank you, Jon.

Comment: @NexTerren It's not the only option, but it is probably the simplest.  You can also do this with a `JsonConverter`.

Comment: sure if you want them to be a string - make them a string!  KISS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JSON format, numbers and booleans do not have quotes around them, while strings do (see [JSON.org](http://json.org/)).

If you want quotes around all your primitives, you have a few options:

1. Change the properties of the object you are serializing to be of type `string`.
2. Put your values into a `Dictionary<string, string>` (or a DTO) and serialize that instead.
3. Make a custom `JsonConverter` to do the conversion.  This option has the advantage that it can apply globally so that you don't have to change all your classes.

The first two options are pretty self-explanatory. If you opted to go with a converter, the code might look something like this:

```
class PrimitiveToStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsPrimitive;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString().ToLower());
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it, simply pass an instance of the converter to the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, new PrimitiveToStringConverter());
```

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo
        {
            Int = 6,
            Bool = true,
            Float = 3.14159
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, new PrimitiveToStringConverter());
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public int Int { get; set; }
    public bool Bool { get; set; }
    public double Float { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{"Int":"6","Bool":"true","Float":"3.14159"}
```

Comment: You should be given *JsonConverter* badge. It seems you can solve everything with it.

Comment: @QtX They are remarkably useful for solving quirky JSON issues; no doubt about that!