# How to serialize JSON without outputting quotes around certain values

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, highcharts, json.net

The short version of problem. In some cases I want no quotes on a string JSon value:

Color =Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]

instead of this:

Color = "Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]"

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

The long details.... I have working code that is a model I made (as proof of concept) of a controller generating all the Json for a HighCharts.com graph on the client.

## 1

Client code (works)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
}

<h2>High Charts Proof of Concept</h2>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        fetchSampleChart1();

        function fetchSampleChart1() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Test1/SampleChart1/',
            type: 'GET',
            //data: '?',
            //data: 'adminEntityID=' + adminEntity + '&fieldName=' + fieldName + '&fieldValue=' + fieldValue + '&outletID=' + outlet,
            complete: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data.responseText);
                var strGraphData = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                if (strGraphData.length == 0) {
                //GraphEmptyDisplay(parmChartId, msg);
                console.log("!!!!GRAPH DATA EMPTY!!!!");
                return '';
                }
                $("#container").highcharts(strGraphData);
            },
            error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //Inject a default error message to the modal target. 
        }
        });
    }

    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

}
```

## 2

Controller Action it calls. Works except it emits quotes on all output where I just want it on most of output.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ContentResult SampleChart1()
    {
        var sc = new HighChartGraph
        {
            Title = new Title() {Text = "Combination Chart"},
            XAxis = new XAxis() {Categories = new string[] {"Apples", "Oranges", "Pears", "Banannas", "Plums"}},
            Center = "[100,80]",
            Size = 100,
            ShowInLegend = false,
            DataLabels = new dataLabels {Enabled = false},
            Labels = new Labels
            {
                Items = new Items
                {
                    Html = "Total Fruit consumption",
                    Style =
                        new Style()
                        {
                            Left = "50px",
                            Top = "18px",
                            //Color = "(Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'"
                            Color="yellow"
                        }
                }
            },
            Series = new List<GraphSeries>
            {
                new GraphSeries
                {
                    GraphType = "column",
                    Name = "Jane",
                    DataSimple = new decimal[] {3, 2, 1, 3, 4}
                },
                new GraphSeries
                {
                    GraphType = "column",
                    Name = "John",
                    DataSimple = new decimal[] {2, 3, 5, 7, 6}
                },
                new GraphSeries
                {
                    GraphType = "column",
                    Name = "Joe",
                    DataSimple = new decimal[] {4, 3, 3, 9, 0}
                },
                new GraphSeries
                {
                    GraphType = "spline",
                    Name = "Average",
                    DataSimple = new decimal[] {3, 2.67m, 3, 6.33m, 3.33m},
                    Marker =
                        new marker
                        {
                            LineWidth = 2,
                            LineColor = "Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]",
                            //LineColor="Black",
                            FillColor = "white"
                        }
                },
                new GraphSeries
                {
                    GraphType = "pie",
                    Name = "Total Consumption",
                    DataExtended = new List<Data>
                    {
                        new Data {Name = "Jane", Y = 13, Color = "Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]"},
                        //new data {Name = "Jane", Y = 13, Color = "Red"},
                        new Data {Name = "John", Y = 23, Color = "Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]"},
                        //new data {Name = "John", Y = 23, Color = "Black"},
                        new Data {Name = "Joe", Y = 19,  Color = "Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]"}
                        //new data {Name = "Joe", Y = 19, Color = "Blue"},
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        //var j=new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(sc); // .NET Serialization will not use  [JsonProperty()] attributes
        var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sc); // Newtonsoft Serialization WILL USE [JsonProperty()] attributes
        //return Json(sc,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // cannot use it will not use our NewtonSoft serialization
        return Content(j, "application/json");
    }
```

## 3 Model It calls to get the JSon:

```
    public class HighChartGraph
    {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public Title Title;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "xAxis")]
    public XAxis XAxis;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "labels")]
    public Labels Labels;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "center")]
    public string Center;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "size")]
    public int Size;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "showInLegend")]
    public bool ShowInLegend;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dataLabels")]
    public dataLabels DataLabels;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "series")]
    public List<GraphSeries> Series;
    }

    public class Title
    {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Text;
    }

    public class XAxis
    {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "categories")]
    public string[] Categories;
    }

    public class Labels
    {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "items")]
    public Items Items;
    }

    public class Items
    {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "html")]
    public string Html;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "style")]
    public Style Style;
    }

    public class Style
    {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "left")]
    public string Left;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "top")]
    public string Top;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "color")]
    public string Color;
    }

    public class GraphSeries
    {
    private string _GraphType;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public string GraphType
    {
        get { return _GraphType; }

        set { _GraphType = value; }

    }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "marker")]
    public marker Marker;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public object Data
    {
        get
        {
        if (DataSimple != null) return DataSimple;
        if(DataExtended !=null) return DataExtended;
        return null;
        }
    }
    [NonSerialized][ScriptIgnore]
    public decimal[] DataSimple = null;

    [NonSerialized][ScriptIgnore]
    public List<Data> DataExtended = null;
    }


 public class Data
    {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "y")]
    public long Y;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "color")]
    public string Color;
    }

    public class dataLabels
    {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "enabled")]
    public bool Enabled;
    }

    public class marker
    {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "linewidth")]
    public int LineWidth;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "linecolor")]
    public string LineColor;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fillcolor")]
    public string FillColor;
    }
```

## 4 As a point of reference here is the HighCharts graph I created the model and sample code from:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/

Comment: Why not simply use `return Json(sc,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet)` ? instead of returning the string  and parsing it again in the client side ?

Comment: The short answer: "In some cases I want no quotes on a string JSon value:"  that's not valid JSON. Nothing that parses JSON will accept it.

Comment: Well `Color =Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]` isn't JSON (at least not valid JSON).  You'll most likely have to write a custom serializer.

Comment: I had been using 
return Json(sc,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
(read where it is commented out). The problem is that it will create the JSon exactly as the properties are named and I need to use 
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "enabled")]
        public bool Enabled;
to fix case issues returning to client and still respect .NET casing conventions for property.

So I switched to 
            var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sc);
            return Content(j, "application/json");
which will respect these attributes.

Comment: As for the "not valid JSON" issue the fiddler sample from vendor is the non-compliant villain there see:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/

Answer (score 2):

HighCharts isn't taking JSON but an actual javascript object. That's why they're able to have executable stuff in it. JSON is very specifically non-executable, data only, for security reasons.

You've got a couple of options here:

- Use JSON as an interchange format, but have a client side function that spins through the JSON, notices if it contains an allowed executable function, eval()'s it, and overwrites the value back into the property.
- Write your own JSONish generator that reflects on the object tree and builds out an executable javascript object vs. JSON
- Hook into JSON.NET and make an ExecutableString type that renders without quotes. It looks like you could make a JsonConverter to do that, along the lines of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21766191/8037. Do like that JsonConverter, except call writer.WriteRaw or writer.WriteRawValue to write out the js.

I don't have to mention that by doing this, you end run around a lot of security features. Eval'ing any code received from an external source could be dangerous. That said, if the feature is proof of concept, and if it's only contacting a server you control and can't be injected a different way, you should be pretty safe.

Comment: I now get that HighCharts is taking a Javascript object that is not JSON, it is JSON plus JavaScript code rather than straight Json.  

So I can solve this by generating a correct JSON object sans the executable JavaScript part, and then either pass the executable part back to client to eval or just have the client do the executable bits and omit them from generated JSon from controller. 

At no point is the JSON combined with user input, nor is the executable JScript mixed with user input so very limited security risk if any.

Comment: writer.WriteRaw(value.ToString());

just will not do the trick. BECAUSE 
[JsonWriterException]: Token PropertyName in state Property would result in an invalid JSON object.  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoComplete(JsonToken tokenBeingWritten)

Its a great idea but NewtonSoft knows what well-formed JSON is supposed to look like and fights bad JSON.

Comment: JsonTextWriter isn't sealed... could you derive that and not call AutoComplete or catch the exception? You can serialize an object with JsonSerializer and JsonTextWriter:

  49:         // Create a serializer
  50:         JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_jsonSerializerSettings);
  51:  
  55:             using (JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding)) { CloseOutput = false })
  56:             {
  57:                 serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, value);
  58:                 jsonTextWriter.Flush();
  59:             }

Comment: Or you could use reflection, grab the _writer field on JsonTextWriter and write to it directly :-P

Answer (score 0):

I would simply update `public class Data` so that instead of putting the string for `Color` and `LineColor` property, you have some kind of enum:

```
new Data {Name = "Joe", Y = 19,  Color = HighchartsCcolor2 }
```

Then on the client, you loop through your `data.responseText` and switch on the `.Color` property. There you would use the value you want based on the enum value.

This would allow you to return valid JSON and handle it however you would like on the client.

Comment: Yes this is a quick proof of concept. A bunch of enums are coming next (graph types, colors, etc.)

I see now the problem is the JSON the vendor is using is invalid and I will take it up with HighCharts support.

As you will see the vendor's examples at:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/
do indeed rely on invalid JSON so it does not make a lot of sense for me to generate invalid JSON that would then be un-parseable on the client.

Comment: From where the JavaScript is running in the example, `Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]` does exist and it evaluates to a value (#f7a35c), so the generated JSON will be valid. The problem is that you are trying to use `Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]` on the server as a literal, which is incorrect. Remember that their code is running on the client and yours is running on the server.

Comment: I understand that Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3] can't be understood on the server, all I ideally wanted was to pass it through without the quotes until I realized that JSON is not valid... The server just needs to generate the JSON that the HighCharts JS on the browser can interpret. Ideally HighCharts may find a better way to deliniate/evaluate their code inside the JSON, I will work with them on it.

I wrote all this code so I am aware what part the client evaluates, and server can generate but not understand. I did not expect .NET to understand that statement just pass-thru.